# Jinja2 not picking up CSS,

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

My jinja2 is not picking up my stylesheet.

code:

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates/'))
template = env.get_template("report1.html")
template_vars = {"title": "Top 20", "stake_indiv": ms[0:21].to_html()}
html_out = template.render(template_vars)

# i then use the HTML to generate a PDF file but it has no stylesheet info
```

I do not get any errors from render or when creating the PDF

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Stake individuals</h2>
    {{stake_indiv}}
</body>
</html>
```

And i have the typography.css file from blueprint css named as style

With no errors i just don't know how to track down the problem

On edit Adding the PDF generation code which is using PyQt4

```
app = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)
web = kit.QWebView()
web.setHtml(html)

printer = gui.QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(gui.QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(gui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName(destination)
web.print_(printer)

app.exit()
```

Comment: What happens if you view the generated HTML in a browser?

Comment: Well that was an obvious test (sorry). Yes it DOES apply the style sheet. (Assuming that the HTML is in the project directory such that ./templates/ would correctly point to the css file.

Therefore who isn't picking up the style sheet? I'm guessing it's my PDF converter.

Comment: Yep, probably the PDF converter. . .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is NOT the Jinja2 processing. If I put the CSS into the body of the HTML, then the rendering uses the CSS and the PDF output is fine. The issue is then in the QT processing and i'll open a separate question for that.